# Tool to simplify boolean expressions with more than 16 inputs

Tags: boolean, expression, simplify

I have very large if conditions and want to simplify them. I am using a tool named Logic Friday and it works fine but now i have more than 16 variables. Is there a tool, website which can do that?

Comment: try this ? http://electronics-course.com/boolean-algebra

Comment: can you post your equation here ?

Comment: (!B && !C && D && !G && H && I && L && M)
                                || (!B && !C && !G && H && I && !L && M && !N)
                                || (!A && !B && !C && D && E && !F && !G && H && I && J && !K && M)
                                || (!A && !B && !C && D && E && !F && !G && H && I && !K && M && !O)
                                || (!A && !B && !C && !E && !F && !G && H && I && !J && L && M && N && O)
                                || (!A && !B && !C && !E && !G && H && I && !J && K && L && M && N && O)

Comment: Thats just a part of it. I wrote  a small programm to "translate" it to something logic friday can understand and the other way. So I don't have to type it...

Comment: @meet thakkar: It does not work with big inputs...